# Update nested Object data in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to give permission to merchants to update their parking data.

The function to update the parking data.

```
exports.updateParking = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const check_exist = await Auth.findById(req.data.id);
    if (!check_exist) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    const _id = req.params.id;

    parkingImage = req.files;

    const updateData = await Parking.updateOne(
      { _id, check_exist: check_exist._id },
      {
        parkingImage,
        price: req.body.price,
        totalSpots: req.body.totalSpots,
        parkingInfo: req.body.parkingInfo,
        "location.address": req.body.location.address,
        "location.city": req.body.location.city,
        "location.state": req.body.location.state,
        "location.country": req.body.location.country,
        "location.zipCode": req.body.location.zipCode,
        "contactInfo.name": req.body.contactInfo.name,
        "contactInfo.phoneNumber": req.body.contactInfo.phoneNumber,
        about: req.body.about,
      }
    );
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "Parking has been updated successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

In the schema some of the data are nested objects like location and contactInfo.

Some of the data are required while adding the parking details like`location:{address, city, state, country}`.

When I pass request like following then *it is updating the data*:

```
{
    "totalSpots": 1,
    "location":{"city": "surat"}, //I am not passing address, state or country still it is working
    "contactInfo":{"name":"anything"}
}
```

But when I pass only `{ "totalSpots": 1 }` Then it is not updating the data instead it is giving an error like: **"{"message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')"}"**

While updating the data it is not mandatory to provide location details so I tried `{runValidators: false}` as a third argument in updateOne but it is giving the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `Object.assign` method.

```
const parking = await Parking.findOne({ _id, check_exist: check_exist._id })
Object.assign(parking, req.body);
await parking.save();
```

This method updates only data you sent from client.
And remember, `req.body` must be same structure as `parking` model.

Comment: Thank you it is working but When I pass ```"location":{"address":"anywhere"}``` It overwrites the data and saves only address. the city, state and country fields is getting deleted

Comment: Yes because that is an object too. You should send all location object or You can do same thing for location object too. I mean you can first `Object.assign(parking.location,req.body.location)` and then do the rest. I suppose that it will work.

Comment: Ok but what if I want to change the location.address then I still need to pass location object fully with all details again with city, state and country? Because if that is the case then I don't think it will be useful

Comment: Did you try the solution I suggested ?

Comment: Yes and it is  working but there are some issues as well